# How to make a static array in javascript class?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, static

A class is made in javascript. I create its objects in differnt other scripts. But I need its one data member(array) to be static?
every time I create a new object of that class then it should not lost that arrays data. I need old array data...

Comment: First of all: there are no classes in JavaScript. Do you mean that you want each object to *start* with a property set to an array of default values, but that later that array could be modified independently on each object?

Comment: No, Javascript does not have classes. There are widely-used hacky ways to fake them, though.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that by 'static' you mean varaibles that are the same no matter which user logs into your site or application?

Comment: @Ali - My understanding is that we are talking about static members, i.e. data which has persistence across all instances of a class. Not across all users or sessions within the whole system?

Comment: @johnnumber: In back-end code (lets say Java) isn't that how static members work? Aren't the the same across all sessions?

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate static members with a property on the constructor. In the example below we have a psuedo-class with a constructor `Foo`. When we create an instance of Foo a reference to the instance is added to Foo's static `instances` property.

```
function Foo () {
    this.description = ' this is the Foo class';
    Foo.instances.push(this); // static member keeps ref to each instance
};

// this is an instance member
Foo.prototype.getDescription = function () {
    return this.description;
}

// this is a static member
Foo.instances = [];
```

So what we're really talking about here is using the constructor as a 'namespace' to hold variables that are in some way related to the 'class'. Its better than using globals because its a little cleaner. As others have said, there are no classes as such but this pattern is conceptually close to static members if you like to think in a class-ical way.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a global variable.

```
<script>
    var myGlobalArray = [];
</script>
```

Comment: I think he needs something to be the same for all instance of users using a website.

Comment: +1. An unhealthy obsession with "making everything an object" (even in non-OO languages! wtf?!) is the problem here. Just make it a global variable as Jakub says, and _move on_.

Comment: @Ali: I see no evidence of that.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to create a private variable and define the prototype methods within the constructor, to be able to use the private variable in the closure.

So, this may approach what you want?

```
function Foo(){
  var staticArr = [];
  if (!('prototypemethodsset' in Foo)){
      var proto = Foo.prototype;
      proto.getArr = function(){
          return staticArr;
      };
      proto.addArr = function(){
           staticArr.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
      };
      proto.prototypemethodsset = true;
  }
}

var f = new Foo
  , g = new Foo;

f.addArr(1,4,8,9,13,7);
g.addArr(5,7);
alert(g.getArr()); //=> 1,4,8,9,13,7,5,7
alert(f.getArr()); //=> 1,4,8,9,13,7,5,7
```